# Mass HTML grabbing tool

Tags: linux, html, ubuntu

I recently found [httpx](https://github.com/projectdiscovery/httpx) and I love it. However, there isn't an option to grab HTML from the sites/IPs I input. Is there a tool that can grab HTML from a long list of websites in a really short amount of time, i.e. making use of my 4 Gbit/s download link?

Comment: Did you try running multiple `wget -i urls.txt`?

Comment: I've tried that, but it splits the data into file names that don't make sense to a computer like index.html.1.